# What does "Failed to zip binaries" mean?

Tags: c, binaries

I have successfully compiled my code, but it says this:

```
Note: You can also run your application by typing 'run' followed by any command line arguments.
Starting application without args...
Checking Libraries...
Copying files...
Processing Files...
Compiling...
Failed to zip binaries!

Application Exited.
```

I want my code to have the user enter three numbers, with spaces in between, and have them be multiplied, so here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mult( int x, int y, int z) {
    return x * y * z;

int main()
    {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    printf("Input two integers to be multiplied: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    scanf("%d", &z);
    printf("The product of the three numbers is %d\n", mult( x, y, z) );
    getchar();
}

int mult (int x, int y, int z)
{
return x * y * z;
    }
}
```

I am using [compilr.com](https://compilr.com/home?action=login) as my development platform.

Comment: Please add platform and compiler information.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus The OP already states he uses compilr.com

Comment: @Bart Thanks. It was hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains syntax errors. `mult` is defined twice, and there are problems with braces. Besides, if you are using C89, `main` should return a value.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code [will simply not link](http://ideone.com/3cv1q). Your first definition of `mult` is missing a brace at the end. Your second (unnecessary) definition seems to have an extra brace following it. As such, there seems to be a single big mult method and no main at all, resulting in the linker error. The main (even if not caught within the braces) doesn't return anything either.

Surprisingly, Compilr doesn't seem to return any errors with regards to this. (Or you don't show us) However, as a consequence of the failure to link, there are no binaries. So when trying to zip them, the actual compression fails with the error message you see.

I would seriously recommend to you to pick up a decent compiler/IDE to compile your code yourself before submitting it anywhere else. Make sure it actually works on your local system first. If compilr.com doesn't return any actual syntax/compiler/linker error information, then it's next to useless for you. (Note that I'm unfamiliar with the system, so it might actually provide it to you. If so, figure out how this works).

Comment: @Dirk Ah, you're right. It fails to link because of the absence of a main. The braces see it included in the function. I'll revise once not on mobile.

Comment: "Surprisingly, Compilr doesn't seem to return any errors with regards to this. (Or you don't show us)" -- compilr.com uses gcc. gcc supports nested functions. It also produced a warning that the OP didn't report: "‘main’ is normally a non-static function". "pick up a decent compiler" -- I think gcc is generally considered to be a decent compiler. People should stop blaming compilr.com when they haven't bothered to try it themselves.

Comment: @JimBalter So my "or you don't show us" applies. I don't use compilr, nor have I ever tried it. I answered under the assumption that the OP provided all information he received, which apparently is not the case.

Comment: I don't use it either. I created an account so that I wouldn't have to assume highly implausible things and wouldn't go around bashing some tool I had never used based solely on the report of an inept beginner. I also bothered to google C local functions to see if any compilers support them.

Comment: @JimBalter Well, aren't you something. Bravo for the extra legwork. Well done. Also, make note that I state "**IF** compilr.com doesn't.... **THEN** it's next to useless for you" followed by an additional disclaimer. At no point did I bash it. But great that you've clarified this.

Comment: @JimBalter You do realize I saw that comment, right? What you don't seem to realize is that I honestly meant you went above and beyond what I have done and (what I assume) a lot would have done. And that I don't think I'm bashing compilr.com or at least I did not mean to.

Comment: I also bothered to follow the link in Dirk's answer below to ideone.com that shows the same error, direct from gcc. What I make note of is that your defense for bashing compilr.com is very poor. You made an unwarranted assumption. And if the OP had run under his local system and it uses gcc, he would have had the same result.

Comment: @JimBalter - As a warning, please don't insult other users in comments. Let's keep things professional here.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that your code is somewhat weird and probably wrong, it seems to me that your error indicates a linker problem: http://ideone.com/iBOtP